# Which is the best web usability book for a non experienced webmaster?

Tags: web-development, website-design, usability

I need an easy to read web usability book for my web programming students. Which one do you consider is the best? I have heard good things about "Don't make me think" from Steve Krug, but I need some others to propose to them.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to "[Don't Make Me Think](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321344758)", there are a few other titles specific to web application design that come to mind, such as:

- "[Rocket Surgery Made Easy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321657292)" by Steve Krug
- "[Designing the Obvious](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321749855)" by Robert Hoekman, Jr.
- "[Web Form Design: Filling in the Blanks](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1933820241)" by Luke Wroblewski
- "[Designing Web Interfaces: Principles and Patterns for Rich Interactions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596516258)" by Bill Scott and Theresa Neil
- "[The Smashing Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003CH11BU)" - Smashing Magazine

But [there are many others](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/74/must-read-user-interface-book/259#259) on usability and UI design in general that apply equally to web apps.

Speaking of web usability, is there an easier way to link to Amazon book titles? I know that StackExchange makes a lot of its money through its Amazon referral links, which is why I took the time to link to them, but there ought to be an easier way to do this.

Comment: +1 on Designing Web Interfaces. Don't Make Me Think is a good place to start though.